Removing typescript globally, but it is still there
I downgraded typescript last night. After that, I can't upgrade anymore. I tried to uninstall globally. Each time I tried to remove, it's still there which I can see by running command tsc -b
`
after running the following command
sudo yarn global remove typescript
I am getting the following error.
yarn global v1.22.19
warning package.json: No license field
[1/2] Removing module typescript...
error This module isn't specified in a package.json file.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global for documentation about this command.


The command for verifying version is tsc -v
